# How to create an dynamic (auto updating) link list for static html site

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, hyperlink, static

I'm looking to make a small static html site with a top navigation menu for the dozen of static html pages that will be the core of the site, something very basic and easy to do...but I would like to add a static blog/news section that will be updated on a daily/weekly basis with several categories within the blog/news section like:

-http://example.com/blog/category1/page1.html

-http://example.com/blog/category2/page2.html

etc..

the blog posts would be simple static html pages uploaded to the server via ftp/sftp.

What I need is a dynamic (auto updating) link list of the blog section of the site to be placed on all the blog posts/pages similar to a Wordpress "latest posts" list and separated from the top navigation menu like:

Recent posts:

- post1
- post2
  etc...

and

Categories:

- category1
- category2.

I have done this before with a small javascript snippet but it was some time ago and I can't find the script anymore :(

The script fetches all the pages and folders within the blog folder makes links of these pages and than displays them on either side of a blog page with different possible configurations like last ten pages uploaded, one list of links per category...there's jquery script out there, it's quiet old (2008) but shows somthing close to what I'm looking for: jQuery File Tree

Thanks in advance for your help and if anyone knows what script I referred to that would be great!

Comment: Use PHP to create dynamic links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398984/creating-dynamic-links-with-php-mysql

Comment: That solves the problem with a MySQL database, I do not use a database just need to scrape all the html files and folders under the Blog folder and show a pre detemined number of links and folders on each blog page

Comment: so in this case you want to fetch your local data. You can do it with some PHP and javascript

Comment: Thanks for the find,  In fact I was looking for a small script similar to the jQuery File Tree script which uses a php file too or the one I previously used but unfortunately that I don't find anymore.

Comment: this is a bit of my work which is doing what you are looking for above this I have an ajax call which calls a PHP file. This code is looking for folder and html files.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026170/how-to-find-a-file-with-javascript

Comment: You have an interesting working script but it does more that what I need as I just need a list of links (the number of links can be deternined) showing on either side of my html blog pages and when someone clicks on a link the page shows up in the same window and not in an iframe if you can modify your script that would be great!

Comment: You can update it. Instead to launch it in an iframe you can append the content to a div and done

Comment: I'm looking to get the same look and feel as a WordPress blog, the links should show like: Recent posts and categories and would need a lot of rewrite of your script